# Recover objects from JSON file using PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

I have a `creds.json` file that has the following structure

```
{
    "username": "Administrator"
    "password": "************"                                                      
}
```

I want to retrieve both "Administrator" and "***********" value using powershell script that I wrote :

```
$creds= (Get-Content C:\Users\lamda\Desktop\creds.json | Out- 
String |  ConvertFrom-Json)
$admin = $creds.username
$password = $creds.password
Write-Host $admin
```

but the following error shows up

> `ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON file is missing a comma as a separator. It should be formatted as such:

```
{
    "username": "Administrator",
    "password": "************"                                                      
}
```

Comment: @MohamedKhalilHannachi just a tip: always validate JSON. You can do that online, for instance [here](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: @MohamedKhalilHannachi you're welcome. If you believe your question has been successfully answered, you can [accept the answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)